# making a single list from 19 lists in python

Tags: python

I have 19 big lists of numbers in python and want to make a new list from all of them. so at the end I would have one list. 
I made the following code for two lists and works perfectly:

```
a2 = [x for x in l2 if x+3 in l1]
```

this code looks for the elements in two lists only if the difference between them is 3. which means it finds any element in l1 if there is an element in l2 which is 3 units bigger than that element in l1 and the new list would have the mentioned elements of l1

for example if `l1 = [1,2,3,6,5,7,8,9]` and `l2 = [4, 6,10,11,13,14]`

```
new = [1,3,7,8]
```

but I don't know how to include the rest of lists. so, instead of looking for the elements in `l2`, it looks for the "3 units bigger elements than `l1`" in l`2 .... l19` and returns the 3 units smaller element in `l1`(the the new list).
do you know how to do that in a single line?

Comment: It would be much easier and pythonic if those lists were contained in a master list rather than just being lists with similar names like `l1`, `l2`, up to `l19`. Could you have them as `biglist[1]`, ..., `biglist[19]`?

Comment: well I have thought of that but the data structure I have is very complicated and if I want to do that it makes my script much less efficient .

Answer (score 2):

Put all of your other lists into a larger list and combine into one set using `set.union`:

```
superlist = [l3, ..., l19]
s = set(l2).union(*superlist)
a2 = [x for x in l1 if x+3 in s]
```

You can, of course, decide to pass the lists directly to `set.union`.

Membership lookup with sets - O(1) complexity - is way faster than that for lists - O(n).

Comment: You can use an empty set() for `.union()` putting l2 into `superlist = [l2, ... , l19]` getting this way more clarity what the code does.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but while membership lookup with sets is O(1), *construction* of the set, which you're doing on every step of the loop, is O(n).  So I'm not sure you're getting the benefits you're hoping for.

Comment: @DSM But if the set only gets constructed once (edited), it'll pay off than multiple list lookups

Comment: @Claudio I've put the set construction outside the comprehension. As per clarity, the first argument still has to be a set.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: that's better. :-)

Comment: @Claudio Well, I'm not sure about that, any pointer to the docs or link would be great :)

Comment: @DSM : I did some testing - you are not missing anything and are fully right (I have learned an interesting lesson here - thanks!)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye : according to my tests usage of set() speeds things so  tiny bit up that it could be neglected (in my test example: 1.44 compared to 1.49 seconds gives 0.05 seconds speedup ).

Comment: @Claudio The speed-up scales with the size of the list and the number of `False` cases in the membership check. You could try with a larger data set.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye : I have tried with 30 Millions elements in a big list (3 times range(10000000) and 9500 in the small (range(500, 10000) ... What do you measure as speedup in your test example?

Comment: @Claudio membership check for `range` objects in Python 3 is O(1). A `range` object is not a list :) I didn't do any tests, the expected speed-up is theoretical and a given.

Answer (score 1):

```
a2 = [x for x in l if x+3 in l1+l2+l3+l4+l5+...+l19]
```

For the sake of completeness, here also another one-liner inspired by the other answers you can use in case of more than 19 lists:

```
a2=[x for x in l if x+3 in set().union(*[eval('l'+str(i+1)) for i in range(19)])]
```

but ...

> **ATTENTION**

such kind of one-liner look very nice, but are **deadly** in case of really large lists (*they can unnecessary take all of your CPU-power for extremely looooong time*), so you will be glad to use a multi-liner instead:

```
bigL = l1+l2+l3+l4+l5+...+l19
setBigL = set(bigL)
a2 = [x for x in l if x+3 in setBigL]
```

For the sake of completeness here how to get `bigL` without the need of writing all the list names:

```
noOfLists = 19; strListAddition = ''
for i in range(19): strListAddition+='l'+str(i+1)+'+'
bigL = eval(strListAddition[0:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your meaning, you can try this, and if you hava 19 list, just change the `range` part:

```
l1 = [4, 6,10,11,13,14]
l2 = [1,2,3,6,5,7,8,9]
l3=[3,7,10,11]

print([x for i in range(2,4) for x in eval('l'+str(i)) if x+3 in l1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 7, 8, 3, 7, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Excellent idea of using eval() , but the provided code doesn't what what requested. Maybe it would if you change x+3 to x-3 ?